# Spring Cloud Config Basic Security throwing 401 error

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I have following configuration on server side:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: "classpath:/config"
  security:
    user:
      name: test
      password: test
```

And following configuration on client side:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      profile: "${spring.profiles.active}"
      uri: "${SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI:http://localhost:8888/}"
      username: test
      password: test
```

I can successfully access properties from browser using `user/pwd` as `test/test`, but when my client tries to fetch it failed with 401 error:

```
INFO 7620 --- [5cee934b64bfd92] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
WARN 7620 --- [5cee934b64bfd92] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: 401 null
```

I tried setting the log level for spring cloud to DEBUG but nothing additional got logged, so I have no clue why I'm getting a 401 from client while I can access properties successfully via browser using the same credentials.

I've also tried removing the security from server and client and it worked perfectly, which means rest of the configurations are quite ok. But then the question is, what am I overlooking when I apply basic security and why it is not working and throwing a 401 instead?

Comment: Can you please update your log properties because as per your described issue it is difficult to find out the cause.You need to update exception or error which is actually occuring .

Comment: Is it sorted now, if yes can you update how.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking these configurations:

- spring.cloud.config.username
- spring.cloud.config.password

Both properties should be defined at bootstrap.properties (not application.properties)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the way you are specifying profile name is correct and if it is getting resolved properly in Java code. You can implement CommandLineRunner and print active profiles from Environment variable.

If you specified property **spring.profiles.active** as native in pom.xml, you can resolve it in application/yaml file as @spring.profiles.active@

If you specified property file as VM argument, then it should work with current implementation.

If you did not specify spring.profiles.active in pom or VM argument, it will resolve to default profile, not native profile. Profile in config client and config server should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have to use bootstrap properties because When the Spring Cloud application starts, it creates a bootstrap context. The bootstrap context is searching for a bootstrap.properties or a bootstrap.yaml file, whereas the application context is searching for an application.properties or an application.yaml file. The bootstrap context is the parent context for the main application

Answer (score 0):

Check the websecurityconfig.java or any other similar file if you are using spring security. Add permitAll() to the api path you are trying to communicate with .